# HDMI video lags on external screen

Tags: nvidia, video, hdmi

I have a recent laptop with ubuntu 20.04 wih a Nvidia GForce 2060, which is correctly installed with nvidia drivers.

When I plug a TV via HDMI, it's detected and works, but the image lags, there's like lag lines in the middle of the screen when the images moves. It's only on the HDMI screen, not the computer screen.

When I start on the windows dual boot there is no lag.

It lags as well with a 360p video as with a 2160p video, I've tried with VLC, and other softwares like Videos, it's the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Yeah is getting worse week after installation...definitely  smth is fkd up...watching movies on 4k screen or using multiscreen via ubuntu is sht...even when you setup your monitor order its changing setup when you sign out...I do not know ubuntu is on the market so many years its cooporate with other satanic brnads and stil cant be faster fkn bill gates sht...